# Can not change ceph configuration

Tags: ceph

I deployed ceph cluster with cephadm on 5 nodes, I am trying to change bluestore_cache_size with this command:

```
sudo ceph config-key set bluestore_cache_size 200221225472
```

but when run this command:

```
sudo ceph-conf --show-config |grep  bluestore_cache
```

always bluestore_cache_size = 0 appears. How I can change this configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ceph tell osd.* injectargs --bluestore_cache_size=200221225472
```

you might need to know about different config

```
The following CLI commands are used to configure the cluster:

    ceph config dump will dump the entire configuration database for the cluster.

    ceph config get <who> will dump the configuration for a specific daemon or client (e.g., mds.a), as stored in the monitors’ configuration database.

    ceph config set <who> <option> <value> will set a configuration option in the monitors’ configuration database.

    ceph config show <who> will show the reported running configuration for a running daemon. These settings may differ from those stored by the monitors if there are also local configuration files in use or options have been overridden on the command line or at run time. The source of the option values is reported as part of the output.

    ceph config assimilate-conf -i <input file> -o <output file> will ingest a configuration file from input file and move any valid options into the monitors’ configuration database. Any settings that are unrecognized, invalid, or cannot be controlled by the monitor will be returned in an abbreviated config file stored in output file. This command is useful for transitioning from legacy configuration files to centralized monitor-based configuration.
```

source: https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/configuration/ceph-conf/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used this command before without any success, am I wrong about using this command to getting report? "ceph-conf --show-config |grep  bluestore_cache"

Comment: can you try this value when initializing the cluster add the entry in the ceph.conf in `[osd]`

Comment: How I can  initializing the cluster?

Comment: you need to set this setting while fresh install